# Slow file dialog in java applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I have a java applet I am using for uploading from interenet explorer in my web site. 
when a button is presse on my site , a javascript function inits the applet and calls the applet's OpenPrivDialog() function.

```
  public void  OpenPrivDialog() {

     AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object run() {
            OpenDialog();
             return true;
        }

     });
 }

 public void OpenDialog(){    

     JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

      fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
      fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
      Logger.getLogger(UploadApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Opening dialog", "fe");
      int retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(f);
      if (retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          Logger.getLogger(UploadApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "approved", "");
           File[] files = fc.getSelectedFiles();
           Logger.getLogger(UploadApplet.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "got " + files.length+" files", "");
           AddFiles(files);
      }  

 }
```

this code works, but is terribly slow the filechooser dilog opens, but for a minute is completely unresponsive and then just extremely slow -any idea why?

Comment: 1) Is it also slow when you trigger the opening of the dialog using a Java button? 2) Why is it being called by JS? 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: no, when the same code is triggered from a button it is not slow.
I want it from a javascript because the button design is part of the html, I want my applet to be independant of the web page design.

Comment: Try searching the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/) & if you find nothing similar, raise a new report.  See what Oracle has to say on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read this post I could picture a horrible experience I had. I needed to work in a software much more complex than yours but in essence it had the same principle: Interacting Java Applet with Javascript running on a web browser.

We faced several issues and I would highlight:

1. **Slow response**: similar to what you are experiencing.
2. **Security issue**: security checks asking the user to agree with
   potentially dangerous code and other issues related with
   zero-day-attacks.
3. **Inoperative Javascript calls**: rarely our applet could not reach the
   javascript code, we never found the reason of this issue and it was
   very hard to reproduce.
4. **Browser compatibility**: Firefox and Chrome were very standard, but we
   faced several problems with Internet Explore and Safari.

It turns out that our applet code was ready in 5 days but the integration with javascript took about a month (we had 4 senior developers working on it) just because our stakeholder wanted it to work with some fancy jQuery components. It was just a ***nightmare***!

Bottom line, we could not do it. Alternatively, we wrote everything within our applet and provided a series of properties that UI developers could use to change the appearance of our applet which worked great and everybody was happy with it.

Therefore, I would advice to do not use JavaScript + Java Applets. Yes, you can use some basic features, but do not go further with it.

Alright, let's talk about your issue. We noticed in some cases that javascript was very slow when calling Java Methods but was never slow when changing Java Propeties. So, we created some Java variables and changed it via Javascript. Next, we watched these variables (maybe in a thread). Finally, we could call the right methods based on these variables.

No, I do not like this approach. But was the only thing that worked for us before drooping the idea of using Javascript with Java Applets completely.

I hope it helps.

Cheers,

Comment: thanks! actually the idea of only changing a variable in the javascript code and watching it in another thread sounds useful. I am going to try this, thanks.